# Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project

Tags: reactjs, npm, command, yarnpkg

I am having this error on cmd everytime I run my RN app if I have download some packages before. Whenever I run yarn command it works, but I dont want to do that all the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: make sure you are running the command in the root of your project

Comment: Yea, forgot to mention , I have installed npm and I am running inside the root of my project.

Comment: Are you making app in react-native ?

Comment: @Pulkit Aggarwal yes, I have mentioned that .

Comment: Please run react-native run-android or react-native start command in your root directory

Comment: Of course I run those commands in the root. That is not the problem! I am running the commands in the right directory. For both commands that you wrote it says the same thing - Unrecognized !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an old issue of React-Native which has no longer been repeated. I think they have fixed this bug so this is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have react-native in your package.json dependencies.
If not, install react-native locally (npm install --save react-native)

Answer (score 0):

First install npm

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then install a yarn

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Check your yarn version

```
yarn --version
```

Then just write a

```
Yarn
```